# significance test by confidence interval in complete randomization design(CRD)

Tags: self-study, inference, multiple-comparisons, experiment-design, biostatistics

In page 91 of this book,   [Design and analysis of experiments by  Montgomery](https://books.google.com.bd/books?hl=en&lr=&id=Py7bDgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA1&dq=design%20and%20analysis%20of%20experiments%20montgomery%20pdf&ots=X6s6s-KU_6&sig=3OtmqxqLGRP9O1pnxIDlqvr1flY&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=design%20and%20analysis%20of%20experiments%20montgomery%20pdf&f=false)  , the author stated after Equation (3.30) that:

> Clearly, if the confidence interval in Equation 3.30
>   includes zero, we would be unable to reject the null hypothesis in Equation 3.25.

In Example 3.3 of page 77, they constructed 95% CI for $\mu_4$, which is $689.68 \le\mu_4 \le 724.32$. This confidence limit also does not contain zero(0). From this, can we say the null hypothesis $\mu_4=0$ is rejected? I am a bit confused because the author doesn't explicitly mentioned it in example 3.3 of page 77.

Comment: If the CI includes 0 then you cannot reject your null hypothesis, since $\mu=0$ is possible with probability greater than $\alpha$..

Comment: Yes, you have evidence against the null hypothesis. Regarding the author's decision not to mentioned it in page 77, I don't know, it could be that this textbook requires prior knowledge of a introductory level course in statistics.